# Can anyone guide me on how to calculate the frequency in hz from wav file? The wave file is of 50 secs

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, frequency

I am using numpy library to calculate freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len_data, 1.0 / rate) , If I am not wrong then this frequency is without unit . **How** **can i convert it into hertz**. I am using the following code :

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile
from scipy import signal

def read_wav_file(file_name):
    sample_rate, Data_audio  = scipy.io.wavfile.read(file_name)
    return sample_rate, Data_audio 

def getFFT(Data_audio, sample_rate):
    len_data = len(Data_audio)
    Data_audio = Data_audio * np.hamming(len_data)
    fft = np.fft.rfft(Data_audio)
    fft = np.abs(fft)
    ret_len_FFT = len(fft)
    freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len_data, 1.0 / sample_rate)
    return ( freq[:int(len(freq))], fft[:int(ret_len_FFT)], ret_len_FFT )

sample_rate_rec, Data_audio_rec = read_wav_file('2020rec.wav')

frequency_rec, fft_rec, ret_lenFFT_rec = getFFT(Data_audio_rec, sample_rate_rec)

print("frequency_rec: " + str(frequency_rec) )

**Output**
frequency_rec: [0.00000000e+00 8.33481508e-03 1.66696302e-02 ... 2.39999833e+04
 2.39999917e+04 2.40000000e+04]


# To convert frequencies into float format
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float':'{:f}'.format})
print("frequency_rec: " + str(frequency_rec) )

**Output**
frequency_rec: [0.000000 0.008307 0.016614 ... 23999.983386 23999.991693 24000.000000]
```

Comment: Your code does not run. Please fix the code first.

Comment: It is running fine let me share more code over here and edit it.

Comment: @orlp  Kindly check again. Thanks.

Comment: You still don't define `rate` anywhere.

Comment: @orlp  Sorry, have made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The numpy FFT package has a built-in function to calculate the frequency vector to go along with your FFT output.  Note that `scipy` outputs the sample *rate* wile `numpy` wants the sample *spacing* so you must invert it first.

```
import numpy as np

def getFrequencies(Data_audio, sample_rate_rec):
    return np.fft.fftfreq(n=len(Data_audio), d=1/sample_rate)
```

Since the output of `scipy.io.wavfile.read` claims to be in samples/sec, the output of `np.fft.fftfreq` will be in cycles/sec aka Hertz.

Comment: I am generating the frequencies above 18 khz and these are stored in a wav file. When I apply the above code then whether the file is of 50 secs or 3 secs . I obtain the frequencies from 0 to 24000 with high interval gap between 2 consecutive frequencies in 3 secs and low interval gap in 50 secs.

Comment: When i am generating the frequencies above 18 khz , then how come i am getting from 0.

Comment: @Andrew What is your sample rate?  The highest frequency you can see in an FFT is 1/2 of the sampling frequency.  The lowest frequency you can see is set by the number of samples you have in your data (you should always through out the 0 point in an FFT).